# function to point to a global nested stucture

Tags: c, pointers, prototype, nested

I am having trouble in writing a function which assigns pointer to the address of global nested structure. 
But i would like that to be done inside a function, not with in main
Please help me in writing the function. Thanks in advance

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct
{
    int c;
}code;

typedef code* p_code ;

typedef struct
{
    char a;
    int b;
    code krish; 
}emp;

emp Global_Sam;

int main()
{
    code tmpcode_krish; 
    code* pcode_krish;

    pcode_krish = &tmpcode_krish;

    printf("Goal %p  %p \r\n ", &(Global_Sam.krish), &(Global_Sam).krish);
    memset(pcode_krish, 0 , sizeof( code));
   // pcode_krish = &Global_Sam.krish;

    PointNestedStructToPointer(&pcode_krish);
    printf("Goal=> both should be same => %p  %p \r\n ", &(Global_Sam.krish), pcode_krish);
    return 0;
}
```

Here,
=> `pcode_krish = &Global_Sam.krish;`
this will point to the global nested structure. But i need to do that inside a function, hence the function, `PointNestedStructToPointer`

```
void PointNestedStructToPointer(p_code *dst )
{
    dst = &Global_Sam.krish;
}
```

The above function doesn't reflect the exact address of the global nested structure, i have put prints a verified. Please help

Comment: Do you expect the variable passed as a destination to point to the global value afterwards, or to just hold the current value?

Comment: @Chris The OP states he wants to mimic `pcode_krish = &Global_Sam.krish` (the commented-out line) via his function call.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the equivalent of

```
dst = &src;
```

Inside a function you have two options:

1. Pass the *address of a pointer* to the function:

   ```
   void doit(code **p)
   {
       *p = &src;
   }

   // later
   doit(&pcode_krish);
   ```
2. Return the pointer from the function and do the assignment yourself:

   ```
   code *doit(void)
   {
       return &src;
   }

   // later
   pcode_krish = doit();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Dereference `dst` when making the assignment in `PointNestedStructToPointer()`:

```
*dst = &Global_Sam.krish;
```

Comment: That makes a local copy of the current global value. It's possible the OP wants it the other way.

Comment: @Chris From `PointNestedStructToPointer()`? The OP's code ran correctly (and compiled without the pesky warning) when I made this fix.

Comment: That's because the OP is passing the address of a temporary value into which to copy the current value of the global.

Comment: @Chris The OP merely prints `pcode_krish` after his assignment. (I'm not sure why he wants it this way, though.)

Comment: I imagine this is a simplified example of the OP's actual code.